# Popular um dataframe vazio com dados de outro dataframe seguindo condições

Tags: python, pandas, loop, dataframe

Estou com dificuldade em visualizar como eu posso solucionar o meu problema com dataframes no Pandas. Vou explicar com exemplos menores:

**Há uma lista que contém 3 dataframes.**

frames = [df_maria, df_joao, df_pedro]

Os 3 dataframes estão no seguinte modelo:

[df_maria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SdgO.png), [df_joao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz71m.png) e [df_pedro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlkFP.png).

**Os itens que englobam a coluna **MODELO** em sua totalidade são modelos de A até Z, 26 no total.**

Foi criado um dataframe vazio com o seguinte formato:

[df_vazio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6x0A.png)

O que eu estou tentando fazer é popular o espaço do **df_vazio['MARIA']** com o valor que consta para os modelos da Maria (df_maria) de acordo com cada tipo de modelo disponível no df_vazio. Então se o df de Maria tiver o modelo X, o valor referente à linha daquele modelo na coluna **quantidade** irá popular o espaço vazio do referido modelo no df_vazio para a coluna da Maria. Depois ele irá verificar o segundo item na coluna modelo de Maria e popular o df_vazio da coluna da Maria naquela linha do modelo, o restante que ele não encontrar irá colocar 0 zero.

Após terminar de verificar e popular o df_maria -> df_vazio, ele irá para o df_joao e fará a mesma coisa, verificando as colunas de cada modelo de João e depois de Pedro.

Eu tentei realizar algumas gambiarras sem sucesso, começando por um **for** dentro de outro **for** que iria percorrer a lista **frames**, algo assim:

```
for i in frames:
    for x in i['MODELO']:
        for y in range(25):
            if x == df_vazio['MODELO'][y]:
                df_vazio['MARIA'][y] = i['QTD'][y]
            else: df_vazio['MARIA'][y] = 0
```

Eu não tenho muita bagagem com lógica de programação e sei que não está correto, ou que existem outros caminhos possíveis que eu desconheço.

Se alguém puder me ajudar ou der uma pista ficarei grato!

Comment: Você está atacando o problema de um jeito estranho. É realmente necessário resolver desta forma? Caso não seja, basta ler sobre join/merge, é o que você precisa para resolver. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: Eu até posso o ajudar, mas para usar o site tem um preço. É preciso que essa pergunta seja formulada de forma que possa ser incorporada em nosso acervo e as amostras e estruturas de dados não devem ficar em links ou no formato de imagens, as incorpore a pergunta no formato de texto(pode ser um código que recria os dfs em python). Veja [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas?cb=1)

Answer (score -2):

Você está atacando o problema de um jeito estranho. É realmente necessário resolver desta forma?

Caso não seja, basta ler sobre join/merge, é o que você precisa para resolver.

Aqui tem um exemplo para começar:

```
import string
import pandas as pd

df_maria = pd.DataFrame([['X', 'MARIA', 23],
             ['Y', 'MARIA', 1],
             ['Z', 'MARIA', 45]],
             columns=['MODELO', 'USER', 'QTD'])

df_joao = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'JOAO', 1],
             ['Y', 'JOAO', 8],
             ['F', 'JOAO', 34]],
             columns=['MODELO', 'USER', 'QTD'])

def geraDf(df_user, user):
    df_vazio_generico = pd.DataFrame(list(string.ascii_uppercase), columns=['MODELO'])
    df_vazio_generico['USER'] = user
    return df_vazio_generico.merge(df_user, on=['MODELO', 'USER'], how='left')\
                    .rename(columns={'QTD':user})\
                    .drop(['USER'], axis=1)

df_vazio = geraDf(df_maria, 'MARIA').set_index('MODELO')\
            .join(geraDf(df_joao, 'JOAO').set_index('MODELO'))\
            .reset_index(drop=False)

df_vazio
```